# CollectionView Cell subviews frame resizing issue in iphone 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uicollectionview, iphone-6

I'm setting the frames of CollectionView Cell subviews according to the size of Cell whose size is set based on screen size . I'm setting cell subviews frames in "CellForItemAtIndexPath" method.In 3.5 & 4 inch phone it is working correctly but in iphone6 frames are being set correctly on scrolling cells i.e., i think on reusability.

Comment: Can you provide some of the code you wrote?

Comment: Following is the code written in "cellForItemAtIndexPath" , frames are calculated in "viewDidLoad"                                                   [cell.teamlabel setFrame:awayTeamViewFrame];
    [cell.gameStartTimeLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(6, -9, gameStartTimeViewWidth-10, cellSize.height)];
    [cell.teamImageView setFrame:teamImageViewFrame];